# EndScreen Not Loading My Best Score And Current Score How To Fix?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make my endscreen save last score and current score but it just appears as 0 for both everytime I die event he I picked up the coins [image](https://gyazo.com/13ea5eddbd6c2df3010244e67906f2f8) ***so basically it isnt saving my coins I had and my coins I have right now***

here is my endScreen

```
#---------------------------------------------------
def endScreen():
    global pause, score, speed, obstacles
    # We need to reset our variables
    pause = 0
    speed = 30
    obstacles = []

    # another game loop  
    run = True
    while run:
        pygame.time.delay(100)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()


        # This will draw text displaying the score to the screen.      
        window.blit(bg, (0,0))
        score = 0
        largeFont = pygame.font.Font('BLOODY.ttf', 80) # creates a font object
        lastScore  = largeFont.render('Best Score: ' + str(updateFile()),1,(255,255,255)) # We will create the function updateFile later
        currentScore = largeFont.render('Score: '+ str(score),1,(255,255,255))
        window.blit(lastScore , (800/2 - lastScore .get_width()/2,150))
        window.blit(currentScore, (800/2 - currentScore.get_width()/2, 240))
        pygame.display.update()





def updateFile():
    f = open('scores.txt','r') # opens the file in read mode
    file = f.readlines() # reads all the lines in as a list
    last = int(file[0]) # gets the first line of the file

    if last < int(score): # sees if the current score is greater than the previous best
        f.close() # closes/saves the file
        file = open('scores.txt', 'w') # reopens it in write mode
        file.write(str(score)) # writes the best score
        file.close() # closes/saves the file

        return score

    return last
#----------------------------------------------------------
```

this is my coins  text where I run it on my main loop

```
    font = pygame.font.Font('times.ttf',29)
    score = 0
    text = font.render("Hearts  =   " + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = ((80,70))
```

and here where is when I die the endScreen loads

````
           if playerman.health < -5:
               endScreen()


```
````

Comment: This looks very similar to [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/183407/39518) - you might want to wait for an answer to that one first, or edit it to include more information rather than posting a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point where your score probably should be displayed to the screen you're setting it to `0` before.

```
        # This will draw text displaying the score to the screen.      
        window.blit(bg, (0,0))
        score = 0
        largeFont = pygame.font.Font('BLOODY.ttf', 80) # creates a font object
        lastScore  = largeFont.render('Best Score: ' + str(updateFile()),1,(255,255,255)) # We will create the function updateFile later
        currentScore = largeFont.render('Score: '+ str(score),1,(255,255,255))
        window.blit(lastScore , (800/2 - lastScore .get_width()/2,150))
        window.blit(currentScore, (800/2 - currentScore.get_width()/2, 240))
        pygame.display.update()
```

When you assign the score to `0` when you leave the loop (when you leave the end screen) your problem should be solved.

Could I help you?